# PHP and HTML select tag

Tags: php, html, tags

I have started with PHP and HTML and would like to execute simple code with three drop-down lists (select tag). But when I make selection from one, the other two selected values disappear. Should I save values when submitting them and then echo. If yes, how can I do it. Sample code will be appreciated.

```
    <?php // formtest_2.php 

$name_vid = $name_type = $name_model = "";

if (isset($_POST['vid']))$name_vid=($_POST['vid']);
else $name_vid="no";

if (isset($_POST['type']))$name_type=sanitizeString($_POST['type']);
else $name_type="no";

if (isset($_POST['model']))$name_model=sanitizeString($_POST['model']);
else $name_model="no";

echo <<<_END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Test Two</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    Make your selection:

<form action="formtest_2.php" method="post">

    <select name="vid" size="1">

    <option value="" selected>Product</option>

    <option value = "apple">apple</option>
    <option value = "cherry">cherry</option>
    <option value = "orange">orange</option>

    </select>

<input type="submit"/><br />        

    <select name="type" size="1">

    <option value="" selected>Color</option>

    <option value = "green">green</option>
    <option value = "red">red</option>
    <option value = "orange">orange</option>

    </select>

<input type="submit"/><br />        

    <select name="model" size="1">

    <option value="" selected>Model</option>

    <option value = "1-a">1-a</option>
    <option value = "2-b">2-b</option>
    <option value = "3-c">3-c</option>

    </select>

<input type="submit"/><br />

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
_END;

echo "Your selection is: $name_vid and $name_type and $name_model"; 

function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);

    return $var;
}
?>
```

Comment: If I understand your question correct, your selection will disappear once you submit. If you want it to remain selected, you should filter the <option> and apply selected='selected' when applicable.

Comment: I have 3 drop down lists. Each has single selection. When I choose from first list apple. It appears like "Your selection is: apple and (nothing) and (nothing)". Next I choose from second list red. It will be like "Your selection is: (nothing) and red and (nothing)". What I would like to have is "Your selection is: apple and red and 3-c".

Comment: I chose Apple, green, 1-c and submitted and this was the result: 
Your selection is: apple and green and 1-a. So don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: Besides, why are making three forms? one form with one submit button should be ok.

Comment: Why it does not work on my browser (Google chrome) then?

Comment: The problem is with combination of your three forms and three submit buttons that have the same name. So after I ch0ose apple, and green, and 1-c which submit button should i click??  Is it mandatory to have three forms?

Comment: I have tried with three lists in one form, and one submit button as well. Same result.

Comment: Mohammad is right. Have changed to one submit button and it works now. But it is interesting that when I submit with one button out of three, the other values become null. Can someone explain me why so?

Comment: check out my answer and tell me if it works. Try on both chrome and firefox

Comment: Is it because when I make submission my page renews and all other values become null?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to reselect values. Since I have only one submit button and it works, I think reselection is not necessary. But the question still on the table. Why after submitting one value other values become null. Is it because of page renewal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, i made one submit button, and re selected the values after submit :

```
<?php
// formtest_2.php

$name_vid = $name_type = $name_model = "";

if (isset($_POST['vid']))
    $name_vid = ($_POST['vid']);
else
    $name_vid = "no";

if (isset($_POST['type']))
    $name_type = sanitizeString($_POST['type']);
else
    $name_type = "no";

if (isset($_POST['model']))
    $name_model = sanitizeString($_POST['model']);
else
    $name_model = "no";


///////////////////
if($name_vid == 'apple')
{
    $v1 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_vid == 'cherry')
{
    $v2 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_vid == 'orange')
{
    $v3='selected';
}
 ////////////////////////
if($name_type == 'green')
{
    $t1 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_type == 'red')
{
    $t2 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_type == 'orange')
{
    $t3='selected';
}


///////////////////////
if($name_model == '1-a')
{
    $m1 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_model == '2-b')
{
    $m2 = 'selected';
}
elseif($name_model == '3-c')
{
    $m3='selected';
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Test Two</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Make your selection:

        <form name="fruite_form" action="formtest_2.php" method="post">

            <select name="vid" size="1">

                <option value="" selected>Product</option>

                <option <?=$v1?> value = "apple">apple</option>
                <option <?=$v2?> value = "cherry">cherry</option>
                <option <?=$v3?> value = "orange">orange</option>

            </select>



            <select name="type" size="1">

                <option value="" selected>Color</option>

                <option <?=$t1?> value = "green">green</option>
                <option <?=$t2?>value = "red">red</option>
                <option <?=$t3?>value = "orange">orange</option>

            </select>



            <select name="model" size="1">

                <option value="" selected>Model</option>

                <option <?=$m1?> value = "1-a">1-a</option>
                <option <?=$m2?>value = "2-b">2-b</option>
                <option <?=$m3?>value = "3-c">3-c</option>

            </select>

            <input name="submitButtom" id="submitButton" type="submit"/><br />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?
echo "Your selection is: $name_vid and $name_type and $name_model";

function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);

    return $var;
}
?>
```

Feel free top add back your submit buttons. 
But give each a unique name and also don't forget to name your form, and as a good practice, give then an id too which will be the same as name attribute.

**Update:** Just to make sure you are really getting a post, since this is your initial question, print this at the end of your code

```
echo $_POST['vid'] . ' ' . $_POST['type'] . ' ' . $_POST['model'] . '<br/><br/>';
```

and see if post really holds the value after submission, if you get a value from post, but not from your assigned variables, then check your conditions used at the top to assign your values.

// you need to check if post isset and has an actual value, only than, the varibale should be assigned. Just like what Sithu said.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to reselect values. Since I have only one submit button and it works, I think reselection is not necessary. But the question still on the table. Why after submitting one value other values become null. Is it because of page renewal?

Comment: No replies and explanations. Anyway, thank you Mohammad and Sithu for help provided.

Comment: Hey man, it was 6:30 so i had to leave the office and reach home.

Comment: As for your null value, if you notice the post was never null after submission, and since you are not printing from the post directly (you assign to another variable) based on condition, that means your condition has something false. Sithu made a good point saying you should force checking on the post before assigning an empty value.

Comment: But it works fine here at my end, so i'm not sure what is causing the problem at your side.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to re-select the values of the drop downs after submission. The following code would be a fix.

```
<?php // formtest_2.php 
$name_vid = $name_type = $name_model = "(nothing)";

if (isset($_POST['vid']) && $_POST['vid']) $name_vid=($_POST['vid']);

if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type']) $name_type=sanitizeString($_POST['type']);

if (isset($_POST['model']) && $_POST['model']) $name_model=sanitizeString($_POST['model']); 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Test Two</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    Make your selection:
    <form action="formtest_2.php" method="post">
        <select name="vid" size="1">    
            <option value="">Product</option>        
            <option value = "apple" <?php if($name_vid == 'apple') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>apple</option>
            <option value = "cherry" <?php if($name_vid == 'cherry') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>cherry</option>
            <option value = "orange" <?php if($name_vid == 'orange') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>orange</option>    
        </select>

        <br />

        <select name="type" size="1">
            <option value="">Color</option>    
            <option value = "green" <?php if($name_type == 'green') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>green</option>
            <option value = "red" <?php if($name_type == 'red') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>red</option>
            <option value = "orange" <?php if($name_type == 'orange') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>orange</option>    
        </select>

        <br />        

        <select name="model" size="1">    
            <option value="">Model</option>    
            <option value = "1-a" <?php if($name_model == '1-a') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1-a</option>
            <option value = "2-b" <?php if($name_model == '2-b') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>2-b</option>
            <option value = "3-c" <?php if($name_model == '3-c') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>3-c</option>    
        </select>

        <input type="submit"/><br />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
echo "Your selection is: $name_vid and $name_type and $name_model"; 

function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);

    return $var;
}
?>
```

I would not use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax ("<<<") to print HTML.

Comment: @user1706819, then, I don't understand what you are trying to do. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @user1706819, did you see my `if` conditions?. `isset` alone is not enough.